# PHP - Store an array returned by a function in an already existing array, one by one

Tags: php, arrays

Very simplified example:

```
function returnArray() {
  return array('First','Second','Third');
}

$arr = array('hello','world');
$arr[] = returnArray();
print_r($arr);
```

I was (wrongly) expecting to see `$arr` containing 5 elements, but it actually contains this (and I understand it makes sense):

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => world
    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => First
            [1] => Second
            [2] => Third
        )

)
```

Easily enough, I "fixed" it using a temporary array, scanning through its elements, and adding the elements one by one to the `$arr` array.

But I guess/hope that there must be a way to tell PHP to add the elements automatically one by one, instead of creating a "child" array within the first one, right? Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`array_merge`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-merge.php),

```
$arr = array_merge($arr, returnArray());
```

will result in

```
Array
(
    [0] => hello
    [1] => world
    [2] => First
    [3] => Second
    [4] => Third
)
```

---

This will work smoothly here, since your arrays both have numeric keys. If the keys were strings, you’d had to be more careful (resp. decide if that would be the result you want, or not), because

> If the input arrays have the same string keys, then the later value for that key will overwrite the previous one. If, however, the arrays contain numeric keys, the later value will not overwrite the original value, but will be appended.

Answer (score 0):

You are appending the resulting array to previously created array. Instead of the use array merge.

```
function returnArray() {
  return array('First','Second','Third');
}

$arr = array('hello','world');
$arr = array_merge($arr, returnArray());
print_r($arr);
```